# Advanced servo control

Tags: python, hardware, arm, servo

I just bought a small robot arm (The MeArm). I can control my servos, but not as I want.  Later I want to control the MeArm with my Wii remote.

About the script I thought about a counter or something?

I want to that the servo moves a little bit when I push a button. It doesn't have to turn smoothly.

Is this possible without a servo controller board?!

Sorry for my bad english but I hope that one of you can help me!

Answer (score 3):

Servos do not require a motor driver board (the servo itself incorporates a driver board).

You just need to supply power via the power and ground wires and a control signal via the control wire.

The control signal is generally a pulse between 1 and 2 milliseconds long transmitted 50 times per second.  The length of the pulse determines the servo angle.

You can generate the needed pulses from the Pi.

If you use an external power supply you need to also connect the Pi ground to the servo ground.

You can connect the servo control wire direct to a Pi GPIO.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library can control the servo.  Alternatively you could use servoblaster or one of its forks.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to install servoblaster or pigpio to control it more specific?

Comment: @RutgerS Yes, either will do for servo control.  They both provide hardware timed pulses with a similar accuracy and resolution to the hardware boards you can buy.